# ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to know what people think of ASP.NET Dynamic Data.  I see the project type in visual studio and have found very little about it mention on blogs and in books.

I created a site using it and it is great the way it wires up the CRUD pages, but i don't understand how to modify the the pages without modifying the template that all the pages use.

Do you think it will be abandoned in future versions of visual studio?  I'm wondering if it's worth the effort of learning this type of application.

personally i think i'd like something simpler....create the CRUD for us, but make them on seperate pages, without the whole template system.

Answer (score 1):

I've always viewed Dynamic Data as an excellent way to create administrative pages...pages that can be thrown up quickly to edit metadata, but which a normal user will never see, so customization becomes less important.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, Dynamic Data takes on far less importance, as the View builders do much of the scaffolding work for you already.